# Remove grave accent from IDs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an ID column with grave accent like this `1234ABC40 and I want to remove just that character from this column but keep the dataframe form.

I tried this on the column only. I have a file name x here and has multiple columns. id is the col i want to fix.

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\filename.csv', index_col = False)
id = str(x['id'])
id2 = unidecode.unidecode(id)
id3 = id2.replace('`','')
```

This changes to str but I want that column back in the dataframe form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataFrames have their own [`replace()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function. Note, for partial replacements you must enable `regex=True` in the parameters:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'id': ["12`3", "32`1"], 'id2': ["004`", "9`99"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["id"] = df["id"].replace('`','', regex=True)

print df

    id   id2
0  123  004`
1  321  9`99
```